# pytest with setup.py test

Tags: python, pytest

I use instructions, that described [here](https://pytest.org/latest/goodpractices.html#integrating-with-setuptools-python-setup-py-test-pytest-runner)

For test I use this command:

```
py.test --ignore=env
```

But if I use

```
python setup.py test
```

**pytest** runs all test (+ in env).

How to skip test in **env** dir?

Thanks!

**UPDATE**

setup.py:

```
from setuptools import setup, find_packages

setup(
    packages=find_packages(),
    setup_requires=['pytest-runner'],
    tests_require=['pytest'],
)
```

Comment: The premise of this question is outdated. See https://stackoverflow.com/a/69525991/21322

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Consider using the [pytest.ini option `addopts`](https://docs.pytest.org/en/stable/customize.html#adding-default-options) like this:

```
# This is pytest.ini in your root directory
[pytest]
addopts = --ignore=env
```

Answer (score 4):

`setup.py test` is deprecated as described in the pytest-runner repo: https://github.com/pytest-dev/pytest-runner#deprecation-notice.

The recommended approach is to call `python -m pytest` directly, as in your first command.