# Adding [aliases] fails with error: invalid command 'xyz'

Tags: python, python-3.x, setuptools, setup.py

Attempting to add shortcuts such as `cov = coverage report --show-missing` to the [`[aliases]`](https://setuptools.readthedocs.io/en/latest/setuptools.html#configuration-file-options) section of setup.cfg causes `python setup.py cov` to fail with `error: invalid command 'coverage'`.  **What additional options are needed to support this?**

Version info:

```
$ python -V
Python 3.7.3
$ pip list | egrep 'setuptools|pip|coverage|pytest'
coverage           5.2.1
pip                20.2.2
pytest             5.4.3
pytest-html        2.1.1
pytest-metadata    1.10.0
setuptools         50.0.0
```

setup.cfg:

```
[aliases]
test = coverage run -m pytest --html=pytest-report.html --self-contained-html
cov = coverage report --show-missing
covhtml = coverage html --title "Coverage report - xyz"

[tool:pytest]
testpaths = tests

[coverage:run]
branch = True
source = pyapp

[options]
# ...
install_requires =
    Flask==1.1.*
    psycopg2==2.8.*
    requests==2.*
    werkzeug==1.*
    click==7.*
setup_requires =
    pytest-runner
tests_require =
    coverage
    pytest
    pytest-html
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[`setup.cfg` aliases](https://setuptools.readthedocs.io/en/latest/setuptools.html#alias-define-shortcuts-for-commonly-used-commands) creates aliases for `setup.py`, not general commands. In your case `python setup.py cov` is equivalent to

```
python setup.py coverage report --show-missing
```

and `setup.py` complains it doesn't have a command `coverage`.

Comment: Hm, okay. But I've seen `[aliases] test = pytest` in several articles. `pytest` is not formally a subcommand, right? So what is it that makes that case work?

Comment: (Second question - I suppose alternatives would be a wrapper-script or a shell `alias`. Any other ideas specific to Python projects?)

Comment: I'm thinking of Node's `scripts` key in package.json, which lets you alias pretty much any `npm` subcommand that you want

Comment: 1. About pytest — I tried the alias and it doesn't work for me; it probably works if `setup.py` [includes](https://stackoverflow.com/q/36391135/7976758) `tests_require=['pytest'],` so that `python setup.py pytest` works.

Comment: 2. If you use `git` for development you can use git aliases.

Comment: Interestingly, running `python setup.py --help-commands` shows `pytest`, `isort`, `flake8` under "Extra commands."  However, switching to `tests_require=['coverage']` doesn't have the same effect. I feel like I'm missing something in terms of how that subcommand is registered.

Comment: Most probably `pytest` has its own integration code which `coverage` doesn't have.

Comment: edit: It occurred to me that using a Makefile fits the bill pretty well here for aliasing common commands within a project.

Comment: alias pytest works because pytest becomes a setuptools subcommand. See https://github.com/pytest-dev/pytest/blob/main/setup.cfg, row 62: `[options.entry_points]`